# Tuleap: cannot not attach file in Tracker

Tags: php, centos, mkdir, tuleap

Trying to attach a file (image) to an artifact in Tracker I've got an error:

```
2018/07/11 13:16:04 [error] 3553#0: *1299 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/tracker/include/Tracker/FormElement/Tracker_FormElement_Field_File.class.php on line 955
PHP message: PHP Warning:  chown(): Operation not permitted in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/backend/Backend.class.php on line 185
PHP message: PHP Warning:  chgrp(): Operation not permitted in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/backend/Backend.class.php on line 222
PHP message: PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/lib/tuleap/tracker/447/105): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/tracker/include/Tracker/FormElement/Tracker_FormElement_Field_File.class.php on line 966
PHP message: PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpinBdbP' to '/var/lib/tuleap/tracker/447/105' in /usr/share/tuleap/plugins/tracker/include/Tracker/FormElement/Tracker_FormElement_Field_File.class.php on line 966" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.73.12.147, server: tuleap, request: "POST /plugins/tracker/?aid=4&func=artifact-update HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "tuleap", referrer: "https://tuleap/plugins/tracker/?aid=4"
```

The artifact is updated without visible errors in GUI, but the changeset is empty, the image is not displayed.

I followed the [full installation process](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/install-el7.html#install-el7) when set up Tuleap (no Docker).
SELinux is disabled as suggested in this guide.

CentOS 7, Tuleap™ 10.1.99.104

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been a bug in this particular build of Tuleap.

Workaround:

`chown -R codendiadm:codendiadm /var/lib/tuleap/tracker/`

More info in the official bugtracker:
https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=11821